# Scrollbar in Tkinter doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to add a scrollbar to my program but so far none of the tutorials I've found online seem to be any help. Here's a sample of the beginning of the program:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
class ScoringSystem:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Scoring System GUI")
        master.geometry("500x750+75+60")

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
        scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
        yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set
```

This adds a scrollbar just fine, but it doesn't actually scroll.

Comment: What widget are you trying to scroll? The window itself is not scrollable. You need a scrollable widget, like a Canvas or Text. Many people have abstracted that into a scrollable Frame, [including me](https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/3eddfce704db3082e38c84664fc1fdf8).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where is your **root** instanciated?

```
root = Tk()
```

did you assign your scrollbar to the good widget you want to scroll?

Also to connect a vertical scroball to a widget you have to do two things :

1) Set the widget’s yscrollcommand callbacks to the set method of the scrollbar.

2) Set the scrollbar’s command to the yview method of the widget.